# A value of type "void (Test::*)()" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "void (*)()"

Tags: c++, pointers

have an issue with pointer on function,i want to create a pointer on function but when i'm trying to point on which function pointer must points appears an error with next text:
A value of type "void (Test::*)()" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "void (*)()" .
Here is my code:

```
testh.h:
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test {    
public:
    Test();
    void hello();
    void goodBye();
    ~Test();
private:
    void(*b1)();
    void(*b2)();
    void(*functPtrs[1])();
    
};

test.cpp:

#include"testh.h"
Test::Test() {
    b1 = hello;
    b2 = goodBye;
    functPtrs[0] = b1;
    functPtrs[1]=b2;

}
void Test::hello() {
    cout << "hello" << endl;

}
void   Test::goodBye() {
    cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
}
Test::~Test() {

}

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: `functPtrs[1]=b2;` goes out of bounds. `functPtrs` is an array with size 1. `functPtrs[0]` is the last element.

Comment: The problem is that `hello` and `goodbye` are not functions, they are *member* functions.

Comment: One approach to use this function pointer array: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vdZ0AvIcDSCYClql

Comment: A pointer-to-member-function is not a pointer-to-function.